# How to get Colors to Match in a Dual Axis Chart in SSRS?

Tags: colors, charts, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a dual axis chart that is showing a bar graph and a line graph for information about some Animals. I would like to make the "Cats %" (Bar) and "Cats" (Line) to be the same Color. I haven't found any way to get the colors to match? Any ideas?

Example Below:
[image: Chart Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a custom color palette http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239355.aspx

"If you are using a custom palette, you can change the order of the colors to change the color of different series in the chart. "

Comment: With this method how would I get the Colors for "Cat %" and "Cat" to match? What about if I add another animal or eat the cow?

Comment: That poor cow... You should be able to add the same color multiple times in order to get what you need. Also, this is a static method. However, the order that they are used should be used in both should be the same because of how they will be sorted.

Comment: I just verified that it should work. Just put the same color twice, one right after the other (ex. red, red, blue, blue, yellow, yellow, purple, purple).

Comment: what about dynamic number of animals? the poor horse, it wanted to join the heard